# NSScanner, reaching the end of parsing string

Tags: iphone

I have a string that's like

"Condition: ***some text which can have a comma in it but not always***, Type *`more text`* Product: ***more text, can be NULL sometimes***

What I did was:

```
NSString *condition = @"Condition:";
NSString *type = @", Type";
NSString *product = @"Product:";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myString];

[scanner scanString:condition intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToString:type intoString &conditionName];
[scanner scanUpToString:type intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToString:product intoString:&typeName];
[scanner scanString:product intoString:NULL];
// stuck here
```

I don't know how to scan till the end of the string since scanString:intoString: takes a NSString parameter.  I wasn't sure how to put these into a while loop either to scan till the end.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanString:condition intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToString:type intoString:&conditionName];
    [scanner scanString:type intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToString:product intoString:&typeName];
    [scanner scanString:product intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToString:condition intoString:&productName];
    // do something with read variables
}
```

From the docs:

> If the search string (stopString) isn't present in the scanner's source string, the remainder of the source string is put into stringValue, the receiver’s scanLocation is advanced to the end of the source string, and the method returns YES.

So you should just scan up to `condition` again at the end of the string for the next iteration of the loop.